# Pairwise distances of a list of numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, combinatorics

If `X` is a set of numbers, then `ΔX` is a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of numbers, representing pairwise subtractions between each 2 numbers. For example, if `X` is a set of points on a line in increasing order, then `ΔX` is a multiset of pairwise distances between these points. How to write a function that returns pairwise distances for a list of numbers? The below works, but I want a more elegant solution. Please include theory or intuitions, that might provide insight in how to solve similar problems, if possible.

```
pairwise_distances :: [Int] -> [Int]
pairwise_distances [] = []
pairwise_distances [x] = []
pairwise_distances (x:xs) = sort $ map (abs . (x-)) xs ++ pairwise_distances xs

pairwise_distances [3,2,1] -- [1,1,2]
pairwise_distances [0,2,4,7,10] -- [2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is spelled like it sounds.

```
 f xs = [x-x' | x <- xs, x' <- xs]
```

This of course will have each pair counted twice, once in order and once in reverse order, so half of the distances will be negative. Depending on what exactly you need, you may use this, or one of the following:

```
f xs = [abs(x-x') | x <- xs, x' <- xs]

f xs = [x-x' | x <- xs, x' <- xs, x>x']
```

The latter relies on xs being a set, i.e. no duplicate points in it, and no zero distances that should be included in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
distances xs = sort [ y - x | (x:ys) <- tails (sort xs), y <- ys ]
```

Intuition: the idea is to generate all the pairs of distinct elements in `xs`.  Each element has some location in the list. If we take `x` to come before `y` on the list, then `x` is the head of some tail of the list, and `y` is somewhere in the tail of the tail. If you sort `xs` first, then `y >= x`. You could take `abs (y-x)` at the end instead of sorting `xs`.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to separate the generation of lists of pairs from the calculation of differences

```
abs_distance x y = abs (x - y)

pairs []     = []
pairs (x:xs) = map (\y -> (x,y)) xs ++ pairs xs
-- or, with TupleSections enabled,
-- pairs (x:xs) = map (x,) xs ++ pairs xs
```

so that you can write

```
pairwise_distances = sort . map (uncurry abs_distance) . pairs
```

This is certainly cleaner (and, I would argue, more elegant) although it may not be the kind of elegance you are looking for.